# How to set header zIndex?Getting below error:Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to keep my drawer component inside header by changing it's z-index but unable to do so as I am getting the error:Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined

Can anybody let me know where am I going wrong?

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";

    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
    import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
    import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';

    import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
    import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
    import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
    import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
    const drawerWidth = 240;
    const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex:theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width:  drawerWidth,
  },

 toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
});

    class Header extends Component {
      render() {

        return (
          <div>
            <AppBar position="static" style={styles.appBar}>
              <Toolbar style={styles.root}>
                <Typography color="inherit"> NEWS</Typography>
                <Button color="inherit">LOGIN</Button>
                  </Toolbar>
                  <Drawer
            style={styles.drawer}
            variant="permanent"
            style={{
              paper: styles.drawerPaper,
            }}
          >
            <div style={styles.toolbar} />
            <List>
              {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text}>
                  <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
              {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text}>
                  <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Drawer>
            </AppBar>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Header;
```

I am trying to set zindex of appbar greater than the drawer z-index but it is not working

Comment: Your `styles` are `undefined` here: `zIndex:styles.zIndex.drawer + 1,`

Comment: even if i define them,z-index index is not working in appbar component.Please find the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you cannot access the styles object until it is fully instantiated. What you probably want to do is to make `styles` a function which takes the *theme* as an argument and returns your styles object like so:

```
 const styles = theme=>({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex:theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,

});
```

then export your `Header` component by wrapping it with the `withStyles` component wrapper and passing your styles to it like this.

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

Here is the full code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";

    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
    import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
    import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';

    import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
    import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
    import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
    import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
    import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
    import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
    import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
    import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
    const drawerWidth = 240;
    const styles = theme => ({
       root: {
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between"
       },
       appBar: {
           zIndex:theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
       },
       drawer: {
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
       },
       drawerPaper: {
          width:  drawerWidth,
       },

       toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    });

    class Header extends Component {
      render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
              <Toolbar className={classes.root}>
                <Typography color="inherit"> NEWS</Typography>
                <Button color="inherit">LOGIN</Button>
                  </Toolbar>
                  <Drawer
            className={classes.drawer}
            variant="permanent"
            style={{
              paper: styles.drawerPaper,
            }}
          >
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <List>
              {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text}>
                  <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List>
              {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                <ListItem button key={text}>
                  <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={text} />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </Drawer>
            </AppBar>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

Note that these styles passed to your component with the `withStyles` wrapper is accessed with the `classes` props. You can then set a style to a component using the `className` property.

Comment: Even 'withStyles(styles)(Header)' is not working to set the z-index